# Tensorflow Objection Detection slow on Video

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I have trained a tensorflow model based upon [EfficientDet D2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) on my custom dataset(related to football(soccer)).

I tested the model on Images and it works as expected, but the performance for video is very low. I haved downloaded a video from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RE9iQC_ntI) on 360p(the file size is 9MB) and video performance is very low, about 5-9 fps.

The code is as follows

```py
# Necessary Imports
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file('Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_effi_d2/pipeline.config')

detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join('Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_effi_d2/', 'ckpt-4')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap('Tensorflow/workspace/annotations/label_map.pbtxt')

video = cv2.VideoCapture('target.mp4')
size = (640,480)
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
#         image_np = np.array(frame)

#         input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=2,
                min_score_thresh=.30,
                agnostic_mode=False)
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections,size))
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if ret == False:
        print("vid not Present")
        break
video.release()
```

*All Paths are relative to root folder*.
Is there anyway to get bit more performance for detecting objects on video.

**Additional info:**

- No gpu. My laptop is from 2015. I have trained the model on Google colab
- Tensorflow 2.4.1 and Python 3.6.13(virtualenv)
- I'm running the video test locally on my laptop. All the versions of tensorflow match with the google colab ones

Comment: Ending your post with a "Common question" list is not a good idea; better provide the info directly, not in FAQ form (edited).

Comment: Ok didn't know about it